# Как в Django вместо стандартной базы данных db.sqlite3 подключить TinyDb?

Tags: python, django, база-данных

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Что нужно прописать, чтобы подключиться базу данных `TinyDb` к Django? Установил её через

```sh
pip install tinydb
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего ответ таков - с использованием стандартной Django ORM **никак**. В официальной [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/) говорится:

```
Django officially supports the following databases:

    PostgreSQL
    MariaDB
    MySQL
    Oracle
    SQLite
```

Для работы с иной СУБД придётся подключать другую ORM.

Comment: Другая ORM подключается отдельно в Django или это фреймворк надо менять , например на Flask?

Comment: @РусланКамов, сторонние ORM, например, __SQLAlchemy__, могут быть подключены к Django. Сам не пробовал так делать, но это вполне возможно. Если же использовать другой фреймворк, который не имеет встроенной ORM, например, тот же __Flask__, то там не будет труда подобрать нужную ORM. При этом, я не уверен, какие ORM будут поддерживать нужную Вам __tinyDb__